# Inverting screen colors on Nexus 5

Tags: color

On my old phone, Samsung Galaxy sII, there was an option to invert colors. Now I have a Nexus 5, and I don't see that option. Is there a way to invert colors on it? (i.e. have the screen show a negative image, black becomes white and white becomes black.)